# yii2 rest authentication with action can handle both users and guests

Tags: yii2

I use accessToken to authorize users so I want action with optional accessToken
We have this ability in none rest controller
like this:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['login', 'logout', 'signup'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['login', 'signup'],
                    'roles' => ['?','@'],
                ],
                
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

exclude not work because, if users send token to authorize they will consider as a guest, not users.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['authenticator']['except'] =  ['fetch-event','fetch-tournament-event'];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need a custom authenticator.

Answer (score 1):

There is [`optional`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-auth-authmethod#$optional-detail) property that make auth filter handle authentication if the token is present but doesn't throw an exception when token is missing.

All you need to do is to set the action ids in the `optional` property instead of `except` property:

```php
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['authenticator']['optional'] =  ['fetch-event','fetch-tournament-event'];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

Comment: You should use `except` instead of `optional`.

Comment: @Godzilla no they shouldn't. Those two properties do completely different things. The `except` property would skip the execution of filter for given actions. Because of that the `user` component will stay in `guest` state even when the access token is present in request.